# Track new locations in database and push markers on map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is the best way to track if someone has posted new location to database and without refreshing page to push that new location(marker) to map.

So if I'm on a website and map has loaded. Someone creates location nearby, I would like that new marker to pop on map without me refreshing page, but If someone created new location far away from me marker won't popup.

Comment: I don't see how you would do that. You could query your db every x seconds and see if there are new markers, but there could be more than one. There are functions to calculate distances with the API.

Comment: If there is too many users on website that would be to heavy for database if there is query to database every few seconds